# ML.NET Writes too much Temp Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ml.net

I have created ML.NET model(multi-classification), everything seems to work fine on my Dev Machine, but on Production Machine (VM). for each call to the predictionEngine.Predict(sampleData) lots of temp files being created in the c:\Windows\Temp folder, the temps file get too much such that about 1000 call to predictionEngine Generate about 100GB of temp files which in turns used up my Hard drive pretty fast.

I have searched all internet for a solution to this problem, found nothing,
I have tried setting ASP_ENVIRONMENT Variable to PRODUCTION nothing still,

[Temps files looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNFUa.png)

I know it is the ML.NET generating this because when I open one of the temp files it reads 
[temp file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSwFH.png)

Production: 
Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM
Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Development:
Laptop
Windows 10 Pro

Comment: i am currently updatng the ML.NET nuget library package to the latest, just to see if this will fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the issue? If so, may I ask how?